# How to convert uint to string in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, solidity

In Solidity, is there a way I can convert my int  to string ?

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract someContract {

    uint i;

    function test() pure returns (string) {

      return "Here and Now is Happiness!";

    }

    function love() pure returns(string) {

        i = i +1;

        return "I love " + functionname(i) + " persons" ;
    }



}
```

What is functionname?Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two post here are giving the responses :

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/solidity-concatenate-uint-into-a-string

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10932/how-to-convert-string-to-int

```
function uintToString(uint v) constant returns (string str) {
        uint maxlength = 100;
        bytes memory reversed = new bytes(maxlength);
        uint i = 0;
        while (v != 0) {
            uint remainder = v % 10;
            v = v / 10;
            reversed[i++] = byte(48 + remainder);
        }
        bytes memory s = new bytes(i + 1);
        for (uint j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            s[j] = reversed[i - j];
        }
        str = string(s);
    }
```

Regards

Comment: This variant was buggy when I tested it, solution from Oraclize https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol may be better:

function uint2str(uint i) internal pure returns (string){
        if (i == 0) return "0";
        uint j = i;
        uint length;
        while (j != 0){
            length++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
        uint k = length - 1;
        while (i != 0){
            bstr[k--] = byte(48 + i % 10);
            i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }

Comment: Yeah I agree that the version in the answer did not work for me, but the one provided in https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol#L1045 did, as pointed out by Dmitriy above here.

Comment: Also:  solc 0.7.0 does not like `byte(48 + remainder)`.   Cannot explicitly convert uint256 to bytes1.

Answer (score 96):

```
solidity ^0.8.0

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

Strings.toString(myUINT)
```

works for me.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol#L15-L35

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Agreed this should be accepted

Comment: Perfect answer. Also to concatenate strings, `+` doesn't work, but this shall be done with `return string(abi.encodePacked("I love ", Strings.toString(i), " persons"));`

Comment: Now you can do string.concat(s1, s2)  @ChristopheVidal

Answer (score 42):

UPDATE for Solidity 0.8.0:

The `uint2str()` function from https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/provableAPI_0.6.sol is now outdated, and will not work, but here is the updated code, that uses solidity 0.8.0:
(there was an Overflow bug in the last version but solidity <0.8.0 ignored that as it did not affect the answer, but that now throws an error)
`byte` was also changed to `bytes1` and +,-,* and so on work like they would from the SafeMath library.

```
function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len;
        while (_i != 0) {
            k = k-1;
            uint8 temp = (48 + uint8(_i - _i / 10 * 10));
            bytes1 b1 = bytes1(temp);
            bstr[k] = b1;
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
```

Comment: This version works with solidity 0.8.1 !
Please upvote. :)

Comment: Can you modify this to have a decimals parameters?  e.g., if uint is 20000 and decimals is 3, then the result would be 20.

Comment: appriciate the update

Answer (score 6):

Concrete_Buddhas answer does not work in solidity 0.8.0. This is a revised version:

```
 function uint2str(
  uint256 _i
)
  internal
  pure
  returns (string memory str)
{
  if (_i == 0)
  {
    return "0";
  }
  uint256 j = _i;
  uint256 length;
  while (j != 0)
  {
    length++;
    j /= 10;
  }
  bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
  uint256 k = length;
  j = _i;
  while (j != 0)
  {
    bstr[--k] = bytes1(uint8(48 + j % 10));
    j /= 10;
  }
  str = string(bstr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your uint is coming from originally encoding a string into uint

```
string(abi.encode(myUint))
```

Answer (score 2):

The [provable-things](https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol#L1045) code suggested in the comments to the accepted answer worked for me, but my linter threw a warning namely: `"uintToStr": Avoid assigning to function parameters. [security/no-assign-params]`.  The below changes the original code slightly to correct this (reassigning the parameter `_i` to another variable called `number`):

```
    /// @notice converts number to string
    /// @dev source: https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.5.sol#L1045
    /// @param _i integer to convert
    /// @return _uintAsString
    function uintToStr(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
        uint number = _i;
        if (number == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = number;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (number != 0) {
            bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + number % 10));
            number /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer seems correct, it is quite inefficient on large numbers.  Here is how I would do it:

```solidity
function itoa32 (uint x) private pure returns (uint y) {
    unchecked {
        require (x < 1e32);
        y = 0x3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030;
        y += x % 10; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 8; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 16; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 24; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 32; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 40; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 48; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 56; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 64; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 72; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 80; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 88; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 96; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 104; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 112; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 120; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 128; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 136; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 144; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 152; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 160; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 168; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 176; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 184; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 192; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 200; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 208; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 216; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 224; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 232; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 240; x /= 10;
        y += x % 10 << 248;
    }
}

function itoa (uint x) internal pure returns (string memory s) {
    unchecked {
        if (x == 0) return "0";
        else {
            uint c1 = itoa32 (x % 1e32);
            x /= 1e32;
            if (x == 0) s = string (abi.encode (c1));
            else {
                uint c2 = itoa32 (x % 1e32);
                x /= 1e32;
                if (x == 0) {
                    s = string (abi.encode (c2, c1));
                    c1 = c2;
                } else {
                    uint c3 = itoa32 (x);
                    s = string (abi.encode (c3, c2, c1));
                    c1 = c3;
                }
            }
            uint z = 0;
            if (c1 >> 128 == 0x30303030303030303030303030303030) { c1 <<= 128; z += 16; }
            if (c1 >> 192 == 0x3030303030303030) { c1 <<= 64; z += 8; }
            if (c1 >> 224 == 0x30303030) { c1 <<= 32; z += 4; }
            if (c1 >> 240 == 0x3030) { c1 <<= 16; z += 2; }
            if (c1 >> 248 == 0x30) { z += 1; }
            assembly {
                let l := mload (s)
                s := add (s, z)
                mstore (s, sub (l, z))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

The `itoa32` function converts a number below 10^32 into exactly 32 digits, padding it with zeros if necessary.

The `itoa` function calls the `itoa32` up to three times to convert an arbitrary 256-bit number, then concatenates the results and removes leading zeros.  It uses binary search to find out the exact number of leading zeros to be removed and removes leading zeros from a string in-place.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to optionally convert to scientific notation, for instance for a more compact number representation, here's a modifed version for that purpose:

```
function uintToString(uint v, bool scientific) public pure returns (string memory str) {

    if (v == 0) {
        return "0";
    }

    uint maxlength = 100;
    bytes memory reversed = new bytes(maxlength);
    uint i = 0;
    
    while (v != 0) {
        uint remainder = v % 10;
        v = v / 10;
        reversed[i++] = byte(uint8(48 + remainder));
    }

    uint zeros = 0;
    if (scientific) {
        for (uint k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            if (reversed[k] == '0') {
                zeros++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    uint len = i - (zeros > 2 ? zeros : 0);
    bytes memory s = new bytes(len);
    for (uint j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        s[j] = reversed[i - j - 1];
    }

    str = string(s);

    if (scientific && zeros > 2) {
        str = string(abi.encodePacked(s, "e", uintToString(zeros, false)));
    }
}
```

Some unit tests:

```
function testUintToString() public {

    Assert.equal(Utils.uintToString(0, true), '0', '0');
    Assert.equal(Utils.uintToString(1, true), '1', '1');
    Assert.equal(Utils.uintToString(123, true), '123', '123');
    Assert.equal(Utils.uintToString(107680546035, true), '107680546035', '107680546035');
    Assert.equal(Utils.uintToString(1e9, true), '1e9', '1e9');
    Assert.equal(Utils.uintToString(1 ether, true), '1e18', '1 ether');
    Assert.equal(Utils.uintToString(550e8, true), '55e9', '55e9');
}
```

The code snippets above are compatible with solidity `0.6.0`.